# Issues with infinispan cross site replication not working in infinispan 8.2

Tags: caching, backup, replication, infinispan, jgroups

I have two DC at two sub domains , first is UDIT and the second is JBOSS (will be used as Backup Site).

**Changes made in UDIT's domain.xml**

(a) Added `<channel name="xsite" stack="tcp"/>`

(b) Made relay entry as

`<relay site="UDIT">
      <remote-site name="JBOSS" channel="xsite"/>
</relay>`

(c) Then Added JBOSS in the Back up site as

`<distributed-cache name="default" mode="SYNC" segments="20" owners="2" remote-timeout="30000" start="EAGER">
    <locking acquire-timeout="30000" concurrency-level="1000" striping="false"/>
    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
    <backups>
       <backup site="JBOSS" strategy="SYNC" enabled="true" />
    </backups>
</distributed-cache>`

**Changes made in JBOSS's domain.xml**

(a) Added `<channel name="xsite" stack="tcp"/>`

(b) Made relay entry as

`<relay site="JBOSS">
      <remote-site name="UDIT" channel="xsite"/>
</relay>`

(c) Then said this is a remote cache

`<distributed-cache name="default" mode="SYNC" segments="20" owners="2" remote-timeout="30000" start="EAGER">
    <locking acquire-timeout="30000" concurrency-level="1000" striping="false"/>
    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
    <backup-for remote-cache="default" remote-site="UDIT"/>
</distributed-cache>`

Now, I started DC on UDIT and another DC on JBOSS. They both starts fine and join the bridge cluster 'xsite' , but the node UDIT is not able to backup data to JBOSS.

I get this error -

[Server:ServerOne] 11:11:01,220 ERROR [org.jgroups.protocols.relay.RELAY2] (HotRodServerWorker-8-2) Udit:ServerOne: no route to JBOSS: dropping message
[Server:ServerOne] 11:11:11,222 WARN  [org.infinispan.xsite.BackupSenderImpl] (HotRodServerWorker-8-2) ISPN000202: Problems backing up data for cache default to site JBOSS: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for a response from JBOSS (sync, timeout=10000)

I do now know what went wrong... :(

Comment: Your channel xsite is not forming a cluster correctly. Set trace level for org.jgroups, let all servers start (do not run any cache operations, that would give you too much noise) and show the logs.

Comment: Hey @Flavius : Server starts fine. They join the cluster. I can see the message. But putting some key into UDIT and getting it from JBOSS causes issue. You can see log here - http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=94010606233544817088

Comment: This is a log from the Hot Rod client, you need the server log (you'll find that in `domain/servers/UDIT/log/server.log` or something like that - and make sure to set the JGroups logging level in domain.xml)

Comment: The question has been answered here: https://developer.jboss.org/message/952760?et=notification.mention#952760